# Display a list from controller in the view MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4eUb.jpg)I have a controller that gets its data from a user defined function using Entity framwework.I am trying to just display my data in the view and populate my table.

My Controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var description = "Toyota";
        QuotingEngineEntities1 vehicles = new QuotingEngineEntities1();


        List<object> list = new List<object>();

        using (var context = new QuotingEngineEntities1())
        {

            var vehicle = from s in context.fn_GetVehicle(description)
                           select new
                           {
                               s.MAKE,
                               s.MODEL,
                               s.PRICE,
                               s.POWER,
                               s.Transmission
                           };


            list.Add(vehicle.FirstOrDefault());


        }

        ViewBag.list = list;

        return View(ViewBag.list);
    }
```

AND MY View looks like this

```
@foreach (var v in ViewBag.list)
    {
       <li>@v.MODEL</li> //i get an error 
       <br />
    }
```

I finally got it work.i had to loop through the data before adding it to the list.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var description = "Toyota";

            List<fn_GetVehicle_Result> list = new List<fn_GetVehicle_Result>();

                using (var context = new QuotingEngineEntities1())
                {

                   var query = context.fn_GetVehicle(description);

                    foreach (var v in query)
                    {

                      list.Add(v);

                    }

                     ViewBag.list = list;
                }



            return View("Index",ViewBag.list);
        }



enter code here
```

Comment: `<li>@v.MODEL</li>` what error you got?

Comment: What is the name of the view? You need to pass the name of the view followed by the variable or data you will be passing like this.  `return View("View", ViewBag.list);`

Comment: @Joseph i think that's not mandatory to pass `viewbag` in `return` statement isn't it ?

Comment: Create a view model with those 4 properties and use `select new YourViewModel { ....` (you cannot use `object`) And return that model to the view (using `ViewBag` is not good practice`). And since you only want one item, then why are you using a collection?

Comment: I want the whole collection ,im using MODEL just to test

Comment: Edit your question with the error, not in comments.

Comment: If you want the whole collection, then it should not be `FirstOrDefault()` which returns only one

Comment: I was returning everything at first but it was hard to trouble shoot so i use the first one just to test.all i want is to be able to access @@v.MODEL or @@v.MAKE

Comment: Then read the previous comments. Pass a view model, not `object`, and not using `ViewBag`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying use Viewbag with your list data but it is not advisable way to do this and you dont have to add Viewbag into `View()` method. It is sent automatically into view by controller.

I would suggest to use ViewModel or ExpandoObject to send your collection into view. You can implement like following

**//controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

        using (var context = new QuotingEngineEntities1())
        {

            var vehicle = from s in context.fn_GetVehicle(description)
                           select new
                           {
                               s.MAKE,
                               s.MODEL,
                               s.PRICE,
                               s.POWER,
                               s.Transmission
                           };

            dynamic yourmodel = new ExpandoObject(); 
            yourmodel.Vehicles = vehicle.ToList();

        }


        return View(yourmodel);
}
```

**// view**

```
@using YourProject; // Your Project Name 
@model dynamic

@foreach (var v in model.Vehicles)
{
    <li>@v.MODEL</li> 
    <br />
}
```

Comment: Thanks in this case i get an error on yourmodel.Vehicles = vehicle.Tolist().beacause vehicle is not visisble outside of the using statement.

Comment: Yes i solved the problem Thanks. i will paste my code